# How to remove color of input[type="radio"] getting dark and light on hover and click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some inputs of type `radio`. I have change the colour of inner and outer colour using the property of `accent-color`. Now the problem is open hovering over it makes it more darker and when it is clicked (keeping mouse button clicked and not removing the finger from clicked), it makes it more lighter.

You can also seen in the snippet. I tried putting `background-color: transparent` but nothing works.

Expected Result: I just want to keep the red color as it is, not making it more darker on hover or lighter upon pressed click. Color red is for example and actually I am using other colors too.

```css
input[type="radio"]:checked {
            accent-color: red;
}
input[type="radio"]:hover {
            accent-color: red;
}
.radio {
   width: 60px;
   height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" class="radio">
```

Comment: You can't do it, it's default behavior. Create your custom radio button

Comment: @Jai248 that requires JS which some users don't have enabled in their browser, and JS is already quite unreliable. There must be some exotic method to change this in certain browsers lol.

Comment: if there is a way then please add the answer @ParkingMaster :)))

Comment: https://verpex.com/blog/website-tips/how-to-style-checkbox-and-radio-buttons-using-css

Answer (score 0):

You do not need any JavaScript to do this, nor to customize radio buttons at all.

You can use the CSS `appearance` property as well as some browser-fixed versions of it like `-webkit-appearance` for responsiveness.

Here is an example of a radio button that I set `appearance` to `none` which removes the border you see around the radio button. Then, I made a fake border which represents the old one so this border stays the same even when hovering it:

```css
.radio {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border: 2px solid #91919e;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked {
  border-color: red;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" class="radio" name="test">
<input type="radio" class="radio" name="test">
```

Note that this code was just made to mimic the old radio button, but you can change all of the CSS to fit your specific needs.

Comment: But still it is getting dark and light when hover over it. Problem is not border problem is appearance of the colors.

Comment: @fatpotato I just added the hover effects to the example. You can change those or remove them if you want to.

Comment: please read the question again. I have already made the hover. Problem is not hovering effect rather on hover or clicked it is getting lighter and darker respectively.

Comment: Run your code snippet and hover one of your checkbox. Color gets darker. I dont want to do that I want it to remain same .

Answer (score 0):

One way, without JS, is to keep the radio button(s) but encase them in divs which have an after pseudo element on top which has the wanted styling when the input is checked.

```html
<style>
  .radio-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: fit-content;
    height: fit-content;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
  }
  
  .radio-wrapper::after {
    content: '';
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: red 2px solid;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
  }
  
  .radio-wrapper:has(input:checked)::after {
    background-image: radial-gradient(red 0 30%, transparent 30% 100%);
  }
  
  input {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  
  .radio {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
  }
</style>
<div class="radio-wrapper"><input type="radio" class="radio" name="test"></div>
<div class="radio-wrapper"><input type="radio" class="radio" name="test"></div>
```